# Upload APK using python, without extracting the content

Tags: python, apk

I have written a script to generate an APK file and upload to the localhost using python, but when uploading the file python extracts the content within the APK and a zip file get submitted to the server, how can I fix this?

```
    with open('/Users/rasheenruwisha/Projects/rn-fs/testbuild/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk',
              'rb') as f:
        print(f)
        r = requests.post('http://localhost:3000/uploadapk', files={'apk': f})
        rJson = r.json()['data']['link'];
        print(sys.argv[3])
        data = {'email': sys.argv[3],
                'businessId': sys.argv[4],
                'apkurl': rJson}
        url = requests.post('http://localhost:8081/updateAPKURL', json = data)
        print(url.json())
```

Comment: You are not opening and extracting the contents you are passing `requests` an open file descriptor and requests will read the data from the open file descriptor. This will always be the case when using `requests`

Comment: .apk files _are zip files_. It's not being extracted, either the client or the server  (or your file browser) guesses (correctly) that a zip file has been uploaded.